Predicting scattering cross-sections
I realized that I do not really understand the way we define and calculate scattering cross-sections starting from transition probabilities in QM. I will explain my reasoning in a moment but the TLDR of my question is:

How can scattering cross-sections be defined to be finite quantities if particles of definite momenta aren't localized?;
Why does the usual way we calculate them work?.

In classical mechanics
I'll briefly go through how I think the scattering cross-section is defined in classical mechanics. We assume to have some potential $V(\vec r)$ and to throw at it particles with a fixed momentum but uniformly distributed in space. What we are describing is a stream of particles of constant volumetric number density $n$ and velocity $v$, giving rise to a flux of particles $J = nv\; [1/sm^2]$. Depending on the impact parameter ($b$) a thrown particle will take some trajectory and fly away in some direction. We can then choose a portion of solid angle and count how many particles fly in that direction per unit time; we denote this quantity with $f\; [1/s]$. Thanks to the fact that $J$ is known we can relate any number of particles per unit time to an area, the scattering cross section $\sigma = f/J\;[m^2]$. $\sigma$ is finite, although infinitely many particles are thrown to the target, because particles are finite and the bigger the impact parameter is the smaller is the interaction felt. A nice property of $\sigma$ is that, despite its definition, is independent of $J$ ($f$ is actually proportional to $J$). So $\sigma$ is only a function of the impact velocity and the shape of $V(\vec r)$.
In quantum mechanics
Now, we want to define and calculate scattering cross-sections in the context of quantum mechanics. We immediately have to face the problem that particles of definite momenta aren't localized. As a consequence, talking about impact parameters doesn't make sense and every one of the infinitely many particles we throw for each unit of time has the same probability of scattering towards the solid angle we selected. This makes $f$ infinite and therefore $\sigma$ as well. Also, the concept of the particle coming from far away is meaningless if the particle's wave-function permeates all of space. So, it's not clear how, starting from transition probabilities, we can define a scattering cross-section independent of $J$, finite and measurable (POINT 1). Note that this problem goes away if we only want to predict branching ratios (the infinities cancel), but this is not the case${}^*$.
I practically know how scattering cross-sections are calculated: they assume a finite universe of volume $\mathcal{V}$ (or periodic boundary conditions which also apply to the potential $V$) so that they can normalize plane waves, they calculate transition probabilities in first order perturbation theory $\text{d}P = W\text{d}t$, they set $\sigma = W/J$ and $J = v/\mathcal{V}$. Since both the initial and final waves are normalized with $1/\sqrt{\mathcal{V}}$ the dependency of $J$ from $\mathcal{V}$ cancels with that of $W$ and $\sigma$ is independent of it. If we take this procedure as a definition for $\sigma$, it's not clear how this scattering cross-section is related to experiments and reduce to the original definition in the classical limit (POINT 2).
${}^*$There's also a time-independent way of doing scattering in QM but, as far as I know, it allows to predict branching ratios but not scattering cross-sections (I'm probably wrong about this but I've never seen it being used to find $\sigma$).

Related: Why can we treat quantum scattering problems as time-independent?

good question.  On notation for dimensions, definitely square brackets is the norm, so $[T]$, $[L]$ are better than units: $[s]$, $[m]$.  The location of the exponent is less formal, but I'm thinking $[L]^2$ if better than $[L^2]$ because the "base" is the concept of length $L$ as a dimension $[L]$, meanwhile $L^2$ is an area on which dimension-status is imbued via the surrounding $[$, $]$. Dealing with them in the denominator is still a matter of taste, i.e. $1/[T][L]^2$, $1/[T]/[L]^2$ or $[T]^{-1}[L]^{-2}$?
